# Arithmetic properties of the partition function

Tags: reference-request, integer-partitions, modular-forms

Ramanujan mentioned in his paper in 1920 that "it appears that there are no equally simple properties for any moduli involving primes other than these three"

$p(5n+4)\equiv0  \mod 5$ 
$p(7n+5)\equiv0  \mod 7$ 
$p(11n+6)\equiv0  \mod 11$

In 2003, Scott Ahlgren and Matthew Boylan published a paper "Arithmetic properties of the partition function", that confirmed the result.

I am attempting to understand the paper as part of my senior thesis for the next 1.5 years.

I would like to kindly ask:

1. Why have elementary methods fail to prove the statement?
2. What "machinery" do I need? I am under the impression that JP Serre's theory for p-adic modular forms will be key. Would anyone kindly recommend books for a systematic independent study on it?
3. What would be the requisite knowledge required to understand the paper?

Thank you for your kind answers.

Comment: $q$-series are the only tool needed here to prove those equations. I will look for references later!

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I would also like to point out that my question was more on showing that "these three" are the only ones with moduli prime. That is the hard part.

Comment: My bad, I didn't get that part. Does the paper you mention prove that modulo any number there is no other one?